# How do I Hide a post from Google results when I type my url?

Tags: google, wordpress

Right now I'm confused & urgently need some help. My website content is continuously copied by a new website. Sorry but I can't mention my site & the other site.

I searched in Google, how to hide my recent post & I found WP hide post plugin, which worked perfectly on my website & all my recent posts are hidden from the home page, in the search results of my website in tags & everywhere else. The problem is that my content is still copied by the other site.

Then, I came upon the Google results & when it typed in my url, all my recent posts are shown on the first & second page of Google results. Is there any option that the search results will not show my recent posts when I type in my URL?

I would also like to mention one more thing that I also hide the date & time from the post. But still all my recent posts are shown in the Google results, and from the clone.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that removing your site from Google will have any effect on the ability of the other site to copy yours. It will just let them get higher ranking in Google themselves.

Comment: I highly advise letting us look at the situation for you. Otherwise, we cannot even guess at a solution and anything written would be less than a guess.

Comment: I've made some edits to your question, can you double check them to ensure this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can hide your posts from google by utilizing the use of robots.txt or adding robots metatag.

This, of course, wouldn't stop someone else from coping your content. If they make bookmark it they will still be able to visit your website and copy everything.

One way to fight against robots copying your site is to use a service like Tynt ([www.tynt.com](http://www.tynt.com)), it's free and the robot will add a link back to your website. You can also report the other site for copyrighting infringements, and if it really copy your website - the chance is, that Google will take them down.

The bast way is hiding your website completely, with a login system. It all depends of the idea of your website.

Comment: It is not clear that the OPs site was scraped. Often, of late, people simply point their domain to another site- God knows why. We have several questions here in the past year where that is the case or something similar. It is best that the OP files a DMCA complaint with Google and let us determine what exactly happened so that we can properly advise them Otherwise we are just guessing. Advising a service does not solve issues where the domain name points to their site nor does it solve about half or more of the problems this creates.